# Markup/Style best practices: How to efficiently distribute style rules over CSS classes?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, paradigms

Assume that I have some HTML page, and a corresponding CSS file.  I'd like to add rounded corners to some elements.  I want to alternate background colors on every other section.  I want to add a hover state for each section heading.  So forth and so on - I keep styling and styling and styling.

It occurs to me that there are three extremes, where it concerns the "who, what, when, where, why and how" of distributing CSS rules over the markup by class, by id, and by hierarchy.

**Extreme #1:** Every style rule is based on an ID.

**Extreme #2:** Every style rule is based on a class.

**Extreme #3:** Every style rule is based on the DOM hierarchy.

Clearly, the zen of front-end web development would include a healthy balance of class reuse vs. unique rules vs. hierarchy, because any of the three extremes would wreak havoc on browser performance, maintainability, and code size.  I think.  Or am I wrong?  How to tell when a new `.class` is necessary, or the style rules you want to apply can be *safely* shoe-horned into an existing definition?  When are two `#id` rules similar enough that you should pull common code out into a class?  When do you "fork" a class (sometimes you keep the original, and add derivations for all deviate situations ("percolate" in OOP terms), and other times push common rules down into each of the several disjoint deviations - clearly this depends upon the nature (ie, number of rules involved) in the deviation itself).  Are there just circumstances for using purely hierarchical rules?

**Question:** Are there any rules of thumb governing this sort of debate?  What is your experience and/or advice?  Are there good articles, resources, books, lectures (bonus points for "tech talk" style videos), or other content available on the topic?  I'd like to keep the discussion grounded in a few key points (although any commentary is welcome), in no particular order:

- Maintainability (ease of reading, modifying, and adding code)
- DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)
- Time efficiency (time-to-onload; progressive rendering)
- Space efficiency (combined size of the markup & associated styles)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do yourself a favor, check out [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/).

While there are pros and cons to compiling your CSS, the gains from having real variables, mix-ins, and helpers in your pre-compiled CSS is definitely worth at least passing consideration.

Comment: @dskvr: if you like SASS, check out Compass. Compass to SASS is like JQuery to javascript: http://compass-style.org/

Comment: Why have I never heard of this? I think this is what CSS needs.

Comment: What happened to my comment? ... *sigh* ... WOW, compass is big news too. I'm really surprised I haven't heard of any of these. Thanks Damien :D

Comment: No problemo. They're a bit ruby centric, but if you can grok ruby gems you should be good to go.

Comment: Accepting because no one else seems interested in the conversation.  Note that while SASS is a great project, it really doesn't go too far answering the question or addressing the underlying concern.

Comment: @Chris: I'd argue that vanilla CSS makes it difficult to do what you proposed. CSS on it's own is a pretty dumb language, by which I mean that it doesn't have any concept of variables, flow control, or more sophisticated methods of code reuse. By moving the logic and abstracting your design into something more sophisticated, be it ruby or something else, you get around these issues.

Comment: @Damien Wilson: Apologies - re-reading my main points, I see that SASS most definitely falls under the category of "maintainability".  I suppose my last comment was more geared towards the areas of DRYness and efficiency of the *final product*, which are two issues that SASS (itself) does not address.

Comment: Understandable, though I usually look at things from a developer's standpoint. How hard is this to work with? How long does it take to make a change? How easy is it to reuse code? How large are the resulting files? You can't really DRY up CSS without spending a lot of time optimizing both your CSS and HTML, which I think is probably better spent on things that make an tangible difference.

Comment: @Damien Wilson: I hear you - my main points are listed "in no particular order" but there's definitely a reason that maintainability was the first thing to come to mind. ;)